# How to preserve ratio on resizing image with Konva

Tags: jquery, konvajs

I'm working from this sample :

https://konvajs.github.io/docs/sandbox/Image_Resize.html

And I need to keep the ratio and resizing.

So I've update the code like this from :

`var height = bottomLeft.getY() - topLeft.getY();`

To

`var height = (width * image.height()) / image.width();`

And it's working but the anchor doesn't move correctly after.
It should stay on the corners of my image...

I've create a fiddle example : https://jsfiddle.net/vhnvegto/